# What does 'not generic' error mean in angular?

Tags: angular

In the below code -

```
 return this.http.get<IPagedResults<ICustomer[]>> {}
```

I get error as

> IPagedResults is not generic

What does that mean?
But, when I remove `IPagedResults` - `return this.http.get<ICustomer[]>` then the error is gone.

The function code is -

```
getPagedCustomers(page: number, pageSize: number): Observable<IPagedResults<ICustomer[]>> {
  return this.http.get<ICustomer[]>(code ...)
}
```

```
export interface IPagedResults<T>{
  results: T;
  totalRecords: number;
}
```

Comment: What's the definition of `IPagedResults`?

Comment: @BrendanGreen - I have updated the question.

Comment: Hrm wonder if the array is the problem.  If you change `results` to be `Array<T>`, and then do `this.http.get<IPagedResults<ICustomer>> {}` does that make any difference?

Comment: @BrendanGreen - No I am getting error as 'Type 'ICustomer[][]' is not assignable to type 'ICustomer[]'. The code works find without IPagedResults in the return statement but do not understand what does 'not generic' mean and what is the reason?

Comment: Just a sec - is this `angularjs` or just `angular`?

Comment: This is from the open source project - https://github.com/DanWahlin/Angular-JumpStart/blob/master/src/app/core/services/data.service.ts which I replicated to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`interface IPagedResults<T extends ICustomer>`

Comment: When I remove the IPagedResults the code works properly. But, I do not understand why does it shows the error 'not generic' and what does it mean?